# Making mathematical animations with Mathematica

Tags: animation, simulation

I recently stumbled upon the Cycloid and was working on finding its length and such when I found [this animation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cycloid_f.gif) on Wikipedia.

[image]

Strikingly pretty and small in size too (66KB)

So on searching how he made that particular animation and others I stumbled upon [this talk](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0:Zorgit#Commons)

> What software edited the animations?
>
> ... None at all. I used MSVC++ to write a little program that calls some GDI+ functions and draws a multi-layer TIF picture each layer of which is a single frame (Only Math, C++ & some Windows API that are well-documented). ...

I went on searching libraries to program with but ultimately quit because it was too much of a bother.

Somewhile later I saw [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EnvelopeAnim.gif) and thank goodness the author used a software package (MuPAD). But the software costs a lot and is now part of MATLAB, and the size of the `.gif` was way too large.

Finally I've come back to Mathematica and want to know how to go about it.

Don't just tell me the code right away; give me some pointers, text, documentation, other questions, etc.

EDIT : Thank you people, here's my rendering (not exactly, because I used J.M.'s code)

[image]

Comment: Start with the documentation/examples for `Manipulate` and/or `Animate`.

Comment: I'd suggest starting at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/. I haven't looked, but I'd bet at least 10 pence there would be a demonstration like this over there.

Comment: This question appears to be overly broad.  Perhaps it would be better for you to ask how to create the first animation in *Mathematica* and see what you can learn from the answers.  Or, you could ask about the tools that one might use to animate a graphic (e.g. `Animate`).  To simply ask about mathematical animations in general isn't really an answerable question.

Comment: Related: http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/07/15/mathematica-qa-creating-movie-files/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll switch it up a bit: I'll give you somewhat simplified code, and your task is to figure out what I'm trying to do:

```
With[{frames = 15}, 
 Animate[
     ParametricPlot[{u - Sin[u], 1 - Cos[u]}, {u, -$MachineEpsilon, t},
                    Axes -> None,
                    Epilog -> {Line[{{t, 1}, {t - Sin[t], 1 - Cos[t]}}],
                              {AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[{t - Sin[t], 1 - Cos[t]}]}},
                    Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 2 Pi + 1}, {0, 2}}, 
                    PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Red], 
                    Prolog -> Circle[{t, 1}, 1]],
         {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/(frames - 1)}]]
```

You'll want to see [Stan Wagon's treatment](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=EbVrWLNiub4C&pg=PA77) as well. Among other things, he gives a visual demonstration of where the cycloid's parametric equations come from:

[image: rolling penny]

Comment: dude you are amazing.....gosh this one example taught me Mathematica animation using some math I'd done earlier . Crazy

Answer (score 18):

Just the code:)

```
Animate[Show[
Graphics[Translate[Rotate[{Circle[], Thick, Blue, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, -1}}], Red, 
  PointSize[.02], Point[{0, -1}]}, -t], {t , 0}], 
PlotRange -> {{0, 4 Pi}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> {Large, Tiny}, 
Axes -> {True, False}, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}], 
ParametricPlot[{(a - Sin[a]), (-Cos[a])}, {a, 0, t}, 
PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Orange]]], {t, 0.001, 4 Pi}, 
AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to export such an animation, instead of directly using `Animate`, define a function `frame[t_] := Show[Graphics[...PlotStyle->Directive[Thick,Orange]]]` with body as above. Create a table of snapshots: `movie = ParallelTable[frame[t], {t, 0.001, 4 Pi, (4 Pi - 0.001)/100}];`. Then export it to your favorite animated graphics format, e.g.: `Export["rolling.mov", movie]`.