# Creating an animation for time evolution of the path of a particle

Tags: plotting, animation

Suppose a particle has the following path

```
ParametricPlot[{2 (θ - π/2) + 2*Cos[θ], 
  2*(1 - Sin[θ])}, {θ, π/2, 4*π + π/2}]
```

which looks like this

[image]

I want to make an animation of the curve. In fact, if we consider the particle as a blue dot, inside the 2D plane. Then as $\theta$ evolves the blue dot which indicates the particle should follow the path according to the equations and thus leaving a solid line behind it. I tried this

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{2 (θ - π/2) + 2*Cos[θ], 
   2*(1 - Sin[θ])}, {θ, π/2, θmax}], {θmax, π/2, 4*π + π/2}]
```

but it is not working! Why?

What is a simple way to do this?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8832)?

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks! Nope! I didn't! :)

Comment: @J.M.: I did exactly the same thing with `Manipulate` instead of `Animate` in *kglr*'s answer but it didn't work! Let me change the question to this issue.

Comment: Fixing the `PlotRange` and making a small offset to the starting point helps quite a bit (you'll notice a similar strategy being used in the answers of the question I linked to): `Manipulate[ParametricPlot[(* stuff *), {θ, π/2 - $MachineEpsilon, θmax}, PlotRange -> {{0, 8 π}, {0, 4}}], (* stuff *)]`.

Comment: @J.M.: Ah! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick demo of `Animate`:

```
f[θ_] := {2 (θ - π/2) + 2*Cos[θ], 2*(1 - Sin[θ])}

Animate[
 ParametricPlot[f[θ], {θ, π/2, θmax}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 8 π}, {0, 4}}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
  Epilog -> {Point[f[θmax]]}
  ],
 {θmax, π/2, 4*π + π/2}
 ]
```